# How to target with "this" selector?

Tags: jquery, this

I want *p* to be expanded when click on div. But when I click either of two divs, all *p* are expanded, and of course I want to expand *p* which is child of clicked div. Not all of them. That is why I am using this line:

```
        jQuery(this).find("p").toggle(500);
```

But obviously something is wrong. What should I do? Below, I posted more code. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$("p").hide();
    $(this).click(function(){
 jQuery(this).find("p").toggle(500);
 });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
.a{
background-image: url(Images/brandimage_74_238px.gif);
}
.b{
background-image: url(Images/someimage.gif);
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="a">
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa a  aa a a a</p>
</div>

<div  class="b">
<p>bb b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? the first `this` in `$(this).click` has no context yet, you need to attach the `click` event to a node first...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/386tu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("p").hide();
    $(this).click(function(){
 jQuery(this).find("p").toggle(500);
 });
```

You are binding click event to the document. Instead, bind it to div:

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $(this).find("p").toggle(500);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).filter('p').toggle(500);
});
```

You were binding to `document`

Answer (score 0):

You are totally misunderstanding the `this` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
        $(this).click(function(){
            jQuery(this).find("p").toggle(500);
        });
});
```

First you do a jQuery function on `document`, now the `$(this)` selector you use after is referring to the `document`, because it's inside the `$(document).ready` function.

The proper way of doing it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(){
   });
});
```

In my way, you first have a p selector, if you click then `this` refers to `p`. So basically the `click` function is for ALL the `<p>` objects in your HTML, but only the `<p>` you clicked will hide, while with `$("p").hide()` ALL the `<p>` objects would be hidden.

Comment: I understand it, now. In that case you should write "div" instead of "p". But thanks for the point you have made.